# How to switch back to node after doing nvm use iojs?

Tags: node.js, nvm, io.js

I can't change back to node:

```
alex@alex-K43U:~/node/es6$ nvm use 0.12.1
N/A: version "v0.12.1" is not yet installed
```

And it's strange because I have it listed:

```
alex@alex-K43U:~/node/es6$ nvm ls
->  iojs-v1.6.2
         v0.6.7
         v0.8.8
       v0.10.35
        v0.12.1
default -> iojs (-> iojs-v1.6.2)
node -> stable (-> v0.12.1) (default)
stable -> 0.12 (-> v0.12.1) (default)
iojs -> iojs-v1.6 (-> iojs-v1.6.2) (default)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls ~/.nvm/versions/node`?

Comment: @Ben weird I only have io.js inside `nvm/versions`. And the actual node versions are in `/nvm/`.

Comment: Hmm. Then maybe you need to set `NVM_DIR=/nvm` environment variable?